# How to dim status bar in Android using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, statusbar

I am working on an app and I wanted to dim the status bar and nav bar of android as explained here (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim).

```
    // This example uses decor view, but you can use any visible view.
activity?.window?.decorView?.apply {
    systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
}
```

But as I am not proficient in Android/Kotlin I am not able to implement this in a Flutter App.
Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use *setSystemUIOverlayStyle* method to maipulate status bar and systemNavigation Bar color and brightness.Also you can specify the orientation of your application you like using it.
You can do so as follows:

```
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
  class _MyAppState extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.teal.withOpacity(0.2)));
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SomeHome(),
       );
     }
   }
```